# How to call API in R every n seconds?

Tags: r, api, shiny

I'm in the middle of creating a Shiny app that takes advantage of a publicly available [bitcoin price API](https://www.coindesk.com/api/). The documents don't mention any sort of rate limit, but I assume calling one of the endpoints once every minute or so isn't too abusive. I've been trying to find how to programmatically call this API every N seconds, so that my app has the most up-to-date data possible. I've looked around a lot, and have been unable to find any such documentation for R. I looked at the source code for [this example](https://gallery.shinyapps.io/087-crandash/), because this is essentially what I want, but it seems that the API connection code is written in Go.

Does anyone know of any documentation that I could look at to call an API every N seconds that is R-specific? Or maybe even just a general framework that I could build off of?

Comment: Some explanation to the down-votes would be helpful..

Comment: It's downvoted because asking for documentation or framework recommendations is explicitly off-topic. That's a flag reason/close vote reason. Not sure why you don't understand that.

Comment: @Lexi I've seen similar questions gone unflagged and upvoted, so excuse me. I understand now that you've responded, no need to be crass.

Comment: just because others do it doesn't mean it is ok to do. If a question doesn't look closed it's because it may not have been handled in the queues. Sometimes I have had flags age away because the queues are full. It happens. We aren't going to handle every single question because too many get asked per day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shiny provides a function called `invalidateLater` to batch calls to streaming data.

e.g :

```
liveish_data <- reactive({
  invalidateLater(100)
  httr::GET(...)
})
```

More on that : https://rviews.rstudio.com/2017/11/15/shiny-and-scheduled-data-r/